# iPhone Gamecenter sandbox testing can't find player over cellular

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center, cellular-network

I am working on a multiplayer game on the iphone, every thing works fine so far.

I have one iphone 3gs with ios 4.1 and one iphone 4 with ios 4.2, i can only find and start a match if ANYONE of the devices is using with wifi, how can i fix this?

Comment: Is it possible you aren't waiting long enough or waiting so long it's generating a timeout?  Cellular data is notoriously slow, compared to local Wi-Fi.

Comment: i've tried many times, the expectedplayer always return 1 when both devices are using cellular.

Comment: If you can't solve it, use the reachability API from apple to disable the service over Cellular and prompt the user to use Bluetooth or some other means.  I'm sorry, but that might be the only way to truly 'solve' your problem.

Comment: It's just a simply board game and i think it would be less interesting if the game can only play over wifi or bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

Now it's solved, just turn on the push notification (Alert, sound, badge) of the game center in the Settings app and my game can now run on every device regardless it's 3g or wifi.